Copy highlighted text from Word files to one Excel sheet under different cells
I need to read all the Word files in a folder. Wherever there is a highlighted text with XXXX whether it is date or any name it should get copied to the Excel file in that particular cell name Date of any other cell.
Sub ExtractHighlightedText()

    Dim oDoc As Document
    Dim s As String
    With Selection
        .HomeKey Unit:=wdStory 
        With .Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Text = ""
            .Highlight = True
            Do While .Execute
                s = s & Selection.Text & vbCrLf
            Loop
        End With
    End With
    Set oDoc = Documents.Add 
    oDoc.Range.InsertAfter s 

End Sub


Where is the Excel file? Please share sample Doc contents.

Your requirements are far from clear. However, the following Word macro should get you started:
Sub BulkExportHilites()
'NOTE: This code requires a VBA reference to Excel
'to be set, via Tools|References in the VBE
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone
Application.WordBasic.DisableAutoMacros True
Dim strFolder As String, strFile As String, strDocNm As String
Dim r As Long, wdDoc As Document
'Get the folder to process
strFolder = GetFolder
If strFolder = "" Then Exit Sub
'Start Excel
Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application, xlWkBk As Excel.Workbook, xlWkSht As Excel.Worksheet
With xlApp
  'Hide our Excel session
  .Visible = False
  Set xlWkBk = .Workbooks.Add
End With
strDocNm = ActiveDocument.FullName
'Process each document in the folder
strFile = Dir(strFolder & "\*.doc", vbNormal)
Do While strFile <> ""
  If strFolder & "\" & strFile <> strDocNm Then
    Set wdDoc = Documents.Open(FileName:=strFolder & "\" & strFile, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)
    Set xlWkSht = xlWkBk.Sheets.Add: r = 0: xlWkSht.Name = strFile
    With wdDoc
      With .Range
        With .Find
          .Text = ""
          .Forward = True
          .Wrap = wdFindStop
          .Highlight = True
        End With
        Do While .Find.Execute
          r = r + 1
          xlWkSht.Cells(r, 1).Value = .Text
          .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        Loop
      End With
      .Close SaveChanges:=False
    End With
  End If
  strFile = Dir()
Loop
xlWkBk.Sheets("Sheet1").Delete: xlApp.Visible = True
Set xlWkSht = Nothing: Set xlWkBk = Nothing: Set xlApp = Nothing: Set wdDoc = Nothing
Application.WordBasic.DisableAutoMacros False
Application.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsAll
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Function GetFolder() As String
Dim oFolder As Object
GetFolder = ""
Set oFolder = CreateObject("Shell.Application").BrowseForFolder(0, "Choose a folder", 0)
If (Not oFolder Is Nothing) Then GetFolder = oFolder.Items.Item.Path
Set oFolder = Nothing
End Function

The above code loops through all Word documents in the selected folder, outputting any found highlighted content in the document body (not in headers/footers/textboxes/footnotes/endnotes) to worksheets with the corresponding document names in a new Excel workbook.
If you want all the output to go on the same worksheet, use:
Sub BulkExportHilites()
'NOTE: This code requires a VBA reference to Excel
'to be set, via Tools|References in the VBE
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone
Application.WordBasic.DisableAutoMacros True
Dim strFolder As String, strFile As String, strDocNm As String
Dim r As Long, c As Long, wdDoc As Document
'Get the folder to process
strFolder = GetFolder
If strFolder = "" Then Exit Sub
'Start Excel
Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application, xlWkBk As Excel.Workbook, xlWkSht As Excel.Worksheet
With xlApp
  'Hide our Excel session
  .Visible = False
  Set xlWkBk = .Workbooks.Add
End With
strDocNm = ActiveDocument.FullName: Set xlWkSht = xlWkBk.Sheets(1): c = 0
'Process each document in the folder
strFile = Dir(strFolder & "\*.doc", vbNormal)
Do While strFile <> ""
  If strFolder & "\" & strFile <> strDocNm Then
    Set wdDoc = Documents.Open(FileName:=strFolder & "\" & strFile, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)
    r = 1: c = c + 1: xlWkSht.Cells(r, c).Value = strFile
    With wdDoc
      With .Range
        With .Find
          .Text = ""
          .Forward = True
          .Wrap = wdFindStop
          .Highlight = True
        End With
        Do While .Find.Execute
          r = r + 1
          xlWkSht.Cells(r, c).Value = .Text
          .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        Loop
      End With
      .Close SaveChanges:=False
    End With
  End If
  strFile = Dir()
Loop
xlApp.Visible = True
Set xlWkSht = Nothing: Set xlWkBk = Nothing: Set xlApp = Nothing: Set wdDoc = Nothing
Application.WordBasic.DisableAutoMacros False
Application.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsAll
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Function GetFolder() As String
Dim oFolder As Object
GetFolder = ""
Set oFolder = CreateObject("Shell.Application").BrowseForFolder(0, "Choose a folder", 0)
If (Not oFolder Is Nothing) Then GetFolder = oFolder.Items.Item.Path
Set oFolder = Nothing
End Function

